# Why os.path.join can not deal with string format

Tags: python

I want to use os.path.join to gather my file path.
But there have some trouble.
Please help me.

```py
print(sys.argv[1]) #print hw2
path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], '{:s}.txt')
print(path) #print {:s}.txt
```

Why the result is not hw2/{:s}.txt?
I have asked the other people and it can work for them.
My python version is 3.6.8.

Comment: You need to put an `f` in front of the format string and actually use a variable or other expression inside the braces.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; I get `hw2/{:s}.txt` as well.

Comment: @blubberdiblub That is not an f-string. OP doesn't seem to want to interpolate at this point.

Comment: There's no difference between a format string or any other string until you actually try to invoke the string's `format` method.

Comment: Interesting. When I run your code and pass "hw2" as a command-line parameter, the output is `{:s}.txt`. I wonder if this is OS-dependent? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: @blubberdiblub The OP doesn't appear to want any formatting at this point; the goal appears to be to use `os.path.join` to create a format string to be used with `format` *later*.

Comment: Uh, i see. That doesn't sound like a good thing to want, though, which is why this didn't occur to me.

Comment: On Windows this is maybe possibly in some way interpreted as a drive letter, or something else with a special meaning.

Comment: @Kevin Hm, could be: what happens if you change the second argument to something like `{0:s}.txt`? (Possibly unfair, but I'm thinking `join` is treating the `{` as a drive "letter", which makes the second argument an absolute path and so the first argument is ignored. The explicit field number would block that interpretation.)

Comment: @chepner, `os.path.join("hw2", "foo{:s}.txt")` gives me `'hw2\\foo{:s}.txt'`, and `os.path.join("hw2", "{0:s}.txt")` gives me `'hw2\\{0:s}.txt'`. I agree that the colon is being interpreted as a drive letter designator in certain contexts.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Why? It's just a platform-independent way of writing `path = hw2/{:s}.txt`.

Comment: @chepner no, I referred to interpolating after joining. That would somewhat go against the reason to have a portable `os.path.join()`, as you could interpolate all kinds of stuff that breaks assumptions of a disciplined use of `os.path.join()` and related functions.

Comment: @blubberdiblub That problem isn't specific to interpolation; `join` makes no promises that the return value is a valid path; it only ensures that your OS-specific separator is used to join whatever arguments you provide it.

Comment: @chepner I am aware of that, but even so with proper usage of `os.path.join()` you restrict yourself to not do some nasty stuff, like inserting path separators yourself. With altering the result after the fact, it's much more likely that you disregard the restrictions and assumptions and insert stuff you shouldn't. Like path separators.

Comment: @blubberdiblub I don't see why. If anything, it should be *more* obvious that the return value of `os.path.join` is a path that needs to be treated carefully than a string that *might* be passed as an argument to `os.path.join`. I think what's really missing is a function that creates a *file name* rather than just a string, which could *prevent* you from creating a value that contains a path separator. E.g. `make_file_name("foo/bar.txt")` -> `ValueError: file name cannot contain path separator`.

Comment: (And yes, if there were such a function, I would agree that using the return value's `format` method would be bad practice. Ideally, `pathlib` would provide a class whos instances represent single path-name components, whose values couldn't contain a path separator and wouldn't have a `format` method.)

Comment: @chepner pathlib does some of that (`.with_name()`). However, I don't see why interpolating before joining is a non-option. If you're not going to insert path separators yourself, that should be fine. You could argue that joining once instead of hundreds of times (when processing many files) is more performant, but I don't think it's very likely that path component composition is the time critical part of a program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that `os.path.join` on Windows isn't very picky about what it considers a drive letter. The initial `{:` causes the second argument to be treated as an absolute path on drive {, causing the first argument to be ignored.

As a workaround, provide an explicit field number to separate the colon from the first character of the string:

```
path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], '{0:s}.txt')
```

(In my opinion, this is worth a bug report at bugs.python.org.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of chepner, `{:` is the key area. So we can use code below the to avoid this without change any output string.

```
path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], '{name:s}.txt')
print(path.format(name="the real string"))
```